# Delphi 2007 IDE crashes when I try to use "Find References" under Search menu

Tags: delphi, ide, crash, delphi-2007

After upgrading to Windows 7 all seems to work in my Delphi 2007 version except this one.
I know that 2007 is not build for win 7 but I'm not sure that the OS is the reason. My friend is using it without a problem.
When I use "Find Local References" all is fine.

Do you know a fix for this? Some dll registration may be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution! 
When I used Refactor -> Rename menu delphi didn't blew up but kindly show me the error. Unavailable interface call with the name of it.
So after short research I've registered 2 tlb files and all is working now.

..CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin\Borland.Studio.ToolsAPI.tlb

..CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin\Borland.Studio.Interop.tlb

I used tregsvr.exe for the registration without a problem under my x64 system.

P.S. I still wonder what else is not registered during the installation .. hopefully all is good.

Comment: Now you can accept your own response to this question to close it. :)

Comment: Yea. I hope this will be helpful to someone else.

Comment: Over a year later, I ran into this same problem.  Thank you.  I should mention that the executable to use is "tregsvr.exe" not "tregrvr.exe" and that it's in the same bin folder as the ".tlb" files.

Comment: I stumbled on this while trying to figure out why this feature suddenly stopped working in my Dephi XE2 install, where it had been working for months. The answer did the trick for my problem also, thanks.

Comment: Just a command to make it easier: (registers all)
for %5 in ("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\CodeGear\RAD Studio\5.0\bin\*.tlb") do tregsvr %5